# Testing recurring payments in PayPal sandbox

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am in the paypal sanbox testing recurring payments. I have them set to monthly but is there a way to test the recurring payment coming back from paypal sooner than this.?

Any help would be brilliant,

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a product or change an existing one and require daily recurring payments. The key should be **BILLINGPERIOD** and **BILLINGFREQUENCY** but please take a look at [paypal](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECRecurringPayments)

PS: If this doesn't help than please show some code :)

Comment: Good man, I will give this a try and get back as soon as possible